# How to enqueue a Job to ActiveJob without loading the whole rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'd like to enqueue a Job to ActiveJob from different places. Sometimes from command line, sometimes from a cron job. But loading the whole environment every time, just to create an entry in redis doesn't feel very efficient.

Is there an other solution to quickly add a job to ActiveJob without loading the whole Rails-Application.

I know, this should be a job for spring, but (I don't know why) it still takes around 5 seconds:

```
> time rails runner -e production 'SynchronizeStuffJob.perform_later'
[ActiveJob] Enqueued SynchronizeStuffJob (Job ID: 148e34bd-c38c-45c9-86f5-5a959a548ebb) to Sidekiq(default)

real    0m5.122s
user    0m4.385s
sys     0m0.663s
```

Oh and if this matters: I use sidekiq.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveJob needs Rails; you cannot use ActiveJob without booting Rails.

You can create Sidekiq native Worker jobs without booting Rails.

Comment: You can use ActiveJob outside of Rails actually. The documentation isn't great but it is possible.

Comment: can confirm, active jobs can be used without rails. Trickiest part : `gem("activejob")` => `require("active_job")` (notice the underscore when requiring)